# как сохранить в энергонезависимой памяти данные массива, принятые в основном цикле программы

Tags: массивы

Есть задача сохранений uint32_t  данных ( метка RFID) в ранее объявленном массиве. Изначально массив заполнен нулями. В основном цикле происходит заполнение элементов массива. Как сохранить сам массив во FLSH памяти? Ранее делал так

```
const uint32_t array[ ] PROGMEM={0,0,0,0,0};                  // Массив для хранения 
                                                                    ключей во FLASH
```

Но этот массив только для чтения, и переписать данные не удалось

для  массива объявленного как

```
uint32_t array[ ]={0,0,0,0,0};
```

в основном цикле заполняю так

```
if(SAVE_IN_MEMORY){array[a]=IndividID; a=a+1;}
```

по мере получения данных и записи их в массив (количество приятых ключей будет ограничено) - нужно записать в энергонезависимую память  - как поступить?

Comment: Добавьте метку языка, чтобы ваш вопрос с большей вероятностью заметили.

Answer (score 0):

Припаивай FRAM к устройству.

EEPROM не дергают в рантайме обычно иначе устройство не будет надежным. Только для сохранения настроек.

Comment: Спасибо - уже думал над этим  и обязательно воспользуюсь вашим советом